# how to convert a bytes to character in python

Tags: python, unicode, hex

I have a bytes type data like this:

```
b"6D4B8BD5"
```

the data is from a chinese character using unicode-escape code.
it can be generate like this:

```
'测试'.encode('unicode-escape')
```

result:

```
b'\\u6d4b\\u8bd5'
```

how can I convert b"6D4B8BD5" to b'\u6d4b\u8bd5' or
how can I convert b"6D4B8BD5" to '测试'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> str = b"6D4B8BD5"
>>> chr(int(str[0:4], 16))
'测'
>>> chr(int(str[4:8], 16))
'试'
```

Answer (score 1):

`unhexlify` is a function to get the bytes, then decode with the right encoding:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> s = b'6D4B8BD5'
>>> unhexlify(s).decode('utf-16be')
'测试'
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution which returns the correct result and works for any string :)

> Python 3.x

```
def convert(chars):
    if isinstance(chars, bytes):
        chars = chars.decode('ascii')

    chars = [''.join(c) for c in zip(chars[::4], chars[1::4], chars[2::4], chars[3::4])]

    return "".join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in chars])


print(convert(b"6D4B8BD5"))


+++++++

#> python test123.py
测试
```

### Second solution without using lists & etc. Easier and faster.

```
def convert(chars):
    if isinstance(chars, bytes):
        chars = chars.decode('ascii')

    result = ''
    for i in range(len(chars) // 4):
        result += chr(int(chars[4 * i:4 * (i + 1)], 16))

    return result


print(convert(b"6D4B8BD5"))
++++++++

#> python test123.py
测试
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit the reasoning behind this? Thanks!

Comment: here we split 4 following hex codes characters into int16 (0-65535) values and calculate real characters using https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr based on the int16 values. That's because Chinese uses utf-16 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)